# How do I get the body of my method to output properly?

Tags: java, methods

I'm new to Java, and I'm having some trouble with a program I'm writing. In TreatHouse.java, I use a method called passOutCandy, which should cause the values of CandyPot1, CandyPot2, and totalCandy to decrease when candy is passed out to the trick or treaters. The program is running, but it keeps getting stuck at passOutCandy, and it doesn't subtract any candy like it should. Can someone explain why this is happening? Also, any other comments to improve my code will be much appreciated. Thanks!

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Halloween 
{

    public static void main(String[] args) 
   {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Which candy should we give out first? Candy in pot 1 or candy in pot 2?");
        int candyPot = scan.nextInt();

        System.out.println("How much candy did we buy?");
        int totalCandy = scan.nextInt();

        TreatHouse ourHouse = new TreatHouse(candyPot, totalCandy);

        while (ourHouse.getCandyCount() > 0) 
      {
            ourHouse.getCandyStatus(); //tells how much candy is left & other stuff

            System.out.println("\nHow much candy per treater should we give out?");
            int treatsPerTreater = scan.nextInt();
            ourHouse.setTreatsPerTreater(treatsPerTreater);

            System.out.println("Knock, knock...." + "Trick or treat!");
            ourHouse.knockKnock();
            ourHouse.passOutCandy();
        }

        System.out.println("Time to turn off the lights and go to bed!");
        System.out.println("The last candy came from pot number "+ ourHouse.getLastPot());
        System.out.println("Happy Halloween!");
        scan.close();
    }
}


    import java.util.Random;

    public class TreatHouse 
    {
        int candyPot1; //amount of candy in pot 1
        int candyPot2; //amount of candy in pot 2
        int currentPot; //1 or 2
        int totalCandy;
        int currentTreaters; 
        int treatsPerTreater;

        public TreatHouse(int candyPot, int totalCandy) 
       {
          //Constructor
           if (totalCandy<=0)
           {
              System.out.println("We can't give out candy if we dont have any. I think we have some from last year."
                               + "Yep, we have 100 pieces of candy to give out.");
              totalCandy=100;
           }    
          switch(candyPot)
          {
          case 1:
             candyPot=1;
             break;
          case 2:
             candyPot=2;
             break;
          default:
              System.out.println("Invalid input; There is no pot " + candyPot + ", so we will use candy pot 1 first.");
             candyPot=1;
          }                   
           currentPot=candyPot;                    
          //Add if statement to split the candy evenly between the two pots.       
          if (totalCandy>0){ 
             totalCandy=totalCandy;
            candyPot1= (totalCandy/2);
             candyPot2= (totalCandy/2);

          }else if ((totalCandy%2!=0)&&(totalCandy>0))
              candyPot1=(totalCandy/2);
              candyPot2=(totalCandy-(totalCandy/2));  
        }
        public int getCandyCount() {
            return candyPot1 + candyPot2;
        }

        public void passOutCandy()
       {
            //If there are enough treats per treater for the given amount per treater, pass out candy
            //from the current pot and switch to the other one.
            //Else display a message that the treaters have been tricked... (no candy for them.)
            // but do not change the current pot
          if (currentPot==1){
             if (candyPot1>(treatsPerTreater*currentTreaters))
                 candyPot1-=(treatsPerTreater*this.currentTreaters);
                 //switch to pot 2
                 currentPot=2;
          }else if (currentPot==2){
             if (candyPot2>(treatsPerTreater*currentTreaters))
                 candyPot2-= (treatsPerTreater*this.currentTreaters);
                 //switch to pot 1
                 currentPot=1;         
          }else
             System.out.println("Mwhahaha...you've been tricked! No candy for you!!!");        
        }

        //Sets the number of trick or treaters.
        public void knockKnock() {
            Random gen = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());
            this.currentTreaters = gen.nextInt(13) + 1; //1 to 13 treaters.
        }

        //Displays how much candy in each pot, total candy left

        public void getCandyStatus() 
       {
          System.out.println("Candy left in pot 1: " + candyPot1);
          System.out.println("Candy left in pot 2: " + candyPot2);
          System.out.println("Total candy left: " + (candyPot1 + candyPot2));
        }
    //returns the pot number for which candy was last given.
    public int getLastPot() 
   {
   if (currentPot==1){
      currentPot=1;
      return currentPot;

   }else if(currentPot==2)
      currentPot=2;   
        return currentPot;
   }
    public void setTreatsPerTreater(int treatsPerTreater)
   {
        treatsPerTreater=treatsPerTreater;
    }
}
```

Comment: You have `totalCandy=totalCandy;` which does nothing, maybe you're looking for `this.totalCandy = totalCandy;`?.

Comment: @Kayaman I tried that, but passOutCandy still doesn't work the way I want it to. The values just remain the same.

Comment: Well, what do you think `treatsPerTreater=treatsPerTreater;` does?

Comment: It want it to set `treatsPerTreater` to whatever the user inputs. I was just looking at it, and I'm thinking it might be the problem.

Comment: That's the problem when you have the parameter the same name as the variable you want to set. You always need to remember to put `this.` in front of the variable. IDEs will warn you that "assignment has no effect", but if you're not using one, you'll miss it easily. It is unfortunate that Java even allows you to assign values to parameters, since it's bad practice and can result in bugs such as these.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your setTreatsPerTreater, as Kayaman says. The value of the attribute is never updating, and it is 0 by default. So, this line:

```
candyPot1-=(treatsPerTreater*this.currentTreaters);
```

Is equal to:

```
candyPot1-= 0;
```

You must use this.treatsPerTreater.